# content://mms-sms/conversations/ return NullPointerException at Android ICS Samsung

Tags: android, sms, uri, android-contentprovider

I'm developing SMS application and need to listing SMS conversation. I found problem when trying to access content provider using uri `content://mms-sms/conversations/`. It's runs well on Android 2.3 but when run at Android 4.0.3 Samsung galaxy tab 2 it return error :

```
 10-17 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 10-17 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
 ComponentInfo{com.yooi/com.yooi.ui.MainActivity}:
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error
 inflating class fragment 10-17 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):
    at
 android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
 10-17 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):   at
 android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
 10-17 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):   at
 android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128) 10-17
 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):     at
 android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
 10-17 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):   at
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 10-17
 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):     at
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 10-17 09:04:51.035:
 E/AndroidRuntime(22600):   at
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514) 10-17
 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):     at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-17
 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):     at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 10-17 09:04:51.035:
 E/AndroidRuntime(22600):   at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
 10-17 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):   at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557) 10-17
 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):     at
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 10-17 09:04:51.035:
 E/AndroidRuntime(22600): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
 Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment 10-17
 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):     at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
 10-17 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):   at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739) 10-17
 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):     at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 10-17
 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):     at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 10-17
 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):     at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 10-17
 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):     at
 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:273)
 10-17 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):   at
 android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835) 10-17
 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):     at
 com.yooi.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17) 10-17
 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):     at
 android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465) 10-17
 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):     at
 android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
 10-17 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):   at
 android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
 10-17 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):   ... 11 more 10-17
 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600): Caused by:
 java.lang.NullPointerException 10-17 09:04:51.035:
 E/AndroidRuntime(22600):   at
 android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1334) 10-17 09:04:51.035:
 E/AndroidRuntime(22600):   at
 android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:181)
 10-17 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):   at
 android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
 10-17 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):   at
 android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:358)
 10-17 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):   at
 android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:311) 10-17
 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):     at
 com.yooi.ui.SmsThreadListActivity.getThreadListCursor(SmsThreadListActivity.java:146)
 10-17 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):   at
 com.yooi.ui.SmsThreadListActivity.onCreateView(SmsThreadListActivity.java:95)
 10-17 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):   at
 android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:806)
 10-17 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):   at
 android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1010)
 10-17 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):   at
 android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1108)
 10-17 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):   at
 android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4243) 10-17
 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):     at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:673)
 10-17 09:04:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22600):   ... 21 more
```

I'd been spent my time search it on google but still not found the answer. Anyone who know please help me, I'm stuck for this annoying problem :(

Comment: It seem `Samsung galaxy tab 2` change URI path. My code work fine on NexusS running 4.1.2. Because directly access messaging provider is not public sdk so you must bear with it. Root or try to find the real path to `msssms.db`

Comment: Just a note: You should never *rely* on `content://sms` or anything similar as their behavior is not documented and therefore is subject to be changed or removed between devices or versions.

Comment: Thanks Eric, but it is the only way to access SMS database right now, right? the uri path work fine when I add threadID such as: `content://mms-sms/conversations/xxx`, but it's become null pointer when there is no threadID mentioned

Comment: @Jevrier we're experiencing the same problem with SGS-3 `content://mms-sms/conversations` returns `null`. Did you mamage to resolve issue?

Answer (score 5):

List of conversations can be retrieved through this query:

```
Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true"); 
Cursor cursor = context.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

Keypoint here's URI `content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true`.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553046/sgs-3-bug-related-to-sms-conversations-list)

Comment: when I run this query on above 4.0 OS version it only return 11 column  [_id, date, message_count, readcount, recipient_ids, snippet, snippet_cs, read, type, error, has_attachment, status]        I need the thread_id which I get easily on running content://mms-sms/conversations/ this query on 2.3.6 OS version, can you please tell me what need to be done to get the complete column above 4.0 thanks for your concern..

Comment: There is no content type (ct_t) information in the returned table. How do I determine is a message is SMS or MMS?

Comment: @A.J. Use the has_attachment to see. You can still use content://sms-mms/converstions/$threadId here without a problem