# getContentProvider query NullPointerException

Tags: android

I am doing

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations");
if (uri == null)
  return;
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri,
                new String[] {"date"},
                null,  // where
                null,  // whereArgs
                "date desc limit 20");
```

and I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1437)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:185)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:385)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:417)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:360)
at com.xxx.MainActivity.c(Unknown Source)
```

This happens on a few phones (such as Samsung Galaxy S3) but not in other phones. Any idea ?

Comment: Do you have the appropriate permissions?

Comment: yes, as I say it works in most phones

Comment: [Here you go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926141/content-mms-sms-conversations-return-nullpointerexception-at-android-ics-sams)

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't work so well (I want something more complex)

Comment: And it doesn't explain the NullPointer, no ?